# Can't use FTP LIST with FTP User Isolation

Tags: windows, iis, ftp

1. I have created a user and `IIS Manager Users` in IIS8. I want to specifically create these users to access (read/write) a directory via FTP, nothing more, nothing less.
2. I've created a new FTP Site with a `LocalUser` directory in it and a new virtual directory which is named the same as the user.
3. I have assigned the folder rights (for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS), enabled IISManagerAuth authentication for the FTP site and allowed the user in the FTP Authorization Rules.

Everything worked fine so far.
When testing this connection with FileZilla I can connect to the server and successfully log in.

The problem is I never get access to the directory as it can't retrieve the directory listing.

```
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER ***|***
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS **************
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (100,89,2,51,39,17).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using FTP in Passive mode, Most of times it's because of some router and/or firewall interfering with the connection.

Allow FTP Passive port range in your firewall any try again, or connect using Active mode and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks so much, this hint helped me solve the problem. The port range was already entered, but I had to fill out the "External IP address of firewall" too. Now it works like a charm :)